# iphone sort based on two keys

Tags: iphone, sorting, core-data

i have two fields called committee name and meeting date in core data.How can i sort them first based on committees in alphabetical order and then by meeting date as ascending
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"committee name" ascending:YES] autorelease];
NSSortDescriptor *sortByDate = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"meeting date" ascending:YES] autorelease];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortByName,sortByDate,nil]];
```

Feed that into your fetch request, and boom. They are prioritized by the order they are in, when you pass them to the fetch request.

Comment: thanks!..but my problem is i want to do the second sorting in the first sorted values.not again from core data.

Comment: .... so sort the array output of your fetch request? the same technique (NSSortDescriptor) works on NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way would be:

1. fetch the result from coredata without sorting.
2. create two NSSortDescriptors for each sort type, add them to array in the desired sorting sequence and use sortedArrayUsingDescriptors on the array. The returned array will be your desired output.

BEST of Luck!!